# How to implement a REST API Server?

Tags: c++, rest

I am a university student with an intermediate level of C++ programming experience. *I would like to implement a simple REST based API for my application as quickly as possible.*

I have looked at [Casablanca](https://casablanca.codeplex.com/) and [libWebSockets](https://libwebsockets.org/trac/libwebsockets) but the examples posted on their respective sites are a bit over my head. Is there any library that has more beginner oriented tutorials on creating a RESTFUL API Server in C++ ?

**Note:** I am aware that this question has been asked a few times in C# but the answers are over a year or two old and mostly not aimed at beginners. I hope that a new post will yield some fresh answers!

Comment: Why does it have to be C++? Why not use [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) or [node.js](http://nodejs.org) or [Rails](http://rubyonrails.org)?

Comment: https://github.com/eidheim/Simple-Web-Server is actually pretty neat because it uses C++11 lambdas.

Comment: Its not hard to understand REST. Just read up on it would be my advice. If existing solutions are over engineered for your project then just write your own server. Its not too tough. You can use my TCPSocket class if you like :) https://github.com/samredway/ssocks

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, **software library**, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: @erapert It doesn't have to be C++! that just the language that I am most comfortable in. I know a bit about node.js but I don't know much about calling an external function or .exe written in C++ from Node.js

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Sorry Captn. I know my question is a little indirect but sometimes you just need a great opinion in place of a factual answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey I also was new to the whole API game not too long ago. I found that deploying an **ASP.NET Web API** with Visual Studio was a great way to start. The template provided by VS (I'm using 2013) makes it really easy to create your own controllers.

If you look up a couple tutorials on HTTP methods, you can really get the hang of molding your controller(s) to your needs. They map well to the CRUD operations which I'm sure you're looking to perform.

You should also be able to find a library in C++ that will allow you to call each of your controller methods and pass/receive serialized JSON/XML objects. Hope this helped, good luck! :)

Answer (score 12):

[Restbed](https://github.com/Corvusoft/restbed) offers asynchronous client/server capabilities via [ASIO](http://think-async.com/) and C++11. We have lots of [examples](https://github.com/Corvusoft/restbed/tree/master/example) and documentation will be available shortly for those who don't like reading header files.

```
#include <memory>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <restbed>

using namespace std;
using namespace restbed;

void post_method_handler( const shared_ptr< Session > session )
{
    const auto request = session->get_request( );

    int content_length = 0;
    request->get_header( "Content-Length", content_length );

    session->fetch( content_length, [ ]( const shared_ptr< Session > session, const Bytes & body )
    {
        fprintf( stdout, "%.*s\n", ( int ) body.size( ), body.data( ) );
        session->close( OK, "Hello, World!", { { "Content-Length", "13" } } );
    } );
}

int main( const int, const char** )
{
    auto resource = make_shared< Resource >( );
    resource->set_path( "/resource" );
    resource->set_method_handler( "POST", post_method_handler );

    auto settings = make_shared< Settings >( );
    settings->set_port( 1984 );
    settings->set_default_header( "Connection", "close" );

    Service service;
    service.publish( resource );
    service.start( settings );

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The next major feature will allow the ability to dependency inject application layers.

```
auto settings = make_shared< Settings >( );

Service service;
service.add_application_layer( http_10_instance );
service.add_application_layer( http_11_instance );
service.add_application_layer( http2_instance );
service.add_application_layer( spdy_instance );
service.start( settings );
```

Comment: I tried installing it but it failed to build.

Answer (score 6):

https://github.com/pistacheio/pistache looks a good and modern to me. The hello world is just 9 lines long.

However, the project appears to work only on Linux.

Comment: Pistache seems in 2018 not supported on Windows?

Comment: I also tried that library but could not access it from another computer. It works locally though. Any pointer to fix this?

Comment: domain has expired

Comment: `httplib` is even simple, just single file: https://github.com/yhirose/cpp-httplib

Answer (score -3):

i'm not aware of any popular c/c++ rest frameworks to easily achieve this.

generally, RESTful frameworks are more popular for higher level languages such as java/.NET/javascript/python/etc...

implementing a RESTful interface without a framework is possible, but it really isn't ideal.